# How can i trigger this process in sql?

Tags: sql, mariadb

The idea is to make a transaction so for example when I insert the name the surname age and amount of a customer the process will trigger the transaction by using the rate of the rate table and the name surname and age will be the same as the table customer!

```
Create TRIGGER  MYtrigger
    AFTER INSERT trigger.customer 
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO trigger.transaction (
    Name, Surname, Age,Exchange)
    VALUES  (customer.Name,customer.Surname,customer.Age,customer.Amount*rate.Rate);
    END
```

Comment: what database server are you using ?

Comment: Xampp,localhost

Comment: @Koon . . . Those are not database products.  Those are interfaces.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Xampp probably means mariadb

Comment: Yes it is mariadb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The names of the tables should be changed in  the variation of the problem
>
> ```
> >DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `myTrigger`  
> > AFTER INSERT ON `customer` 
> > FOR EACH ROW  
> > BEGIN 
> > INSERT INTO bonus.tra (cus_id ,
> >                         name,
> >                         surname,
> >                         age,
> >                         exchange)
> >                         
> >                         VALUES (
> >                         new.cus_id,
> >                         new.name,
> >                         new.surname,
> >                         new.age,
> >                         new.amount *(SELECT rate_ra from rate));
> >                             END $$ 
> DELIMITER ;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
delimiter $$

Create TRIGGER  MYtrigger AFTER INSERT trigger.customer 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO trigger.transaction (Name, Surname, Age, Exchange)
        VALUES  (new.Name, new.Surname, new.Age, new.Amount*rate.Rate);
END;$$

delimiter ;
```

That said, you'll now have a problem with `rate`.  I don't know what that is, but it suggests something like this:

```
delimiter $$

Create TRIGGER  MYtrigger AFTER INSERT trigger.customer 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO trigger.transaction (Name, Surname, Age, Exchange)
        SELECT new.Name, new.Surname, new.Age, new.Amount*r.Rate
        FROM rate r
        WHERE r.? = new.?;  -- not the faintest idea what is used for the match
END;$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: @Koon  . . . Well, that is totally vague and provides no information.